# can't find a 3uf.5uf,5uf 250vac 5 wire Ceiling Fan Capacitor what can I use instead?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I've searched the internet and closet I've come to the 3uf,5uf,5uf is 4uf,5uf,5uf can I use it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you could use individual motor run capacitors. of 3, 5, and 5uF

4,5,5 is probably close enough, especially if the 3 is only used in the speed control circuit